# Is there a way to check if JS thread is busy?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

There are some heavy computations that I want to run on my react native app but I only want to run them once react has finished rendering all UI. Is there a way to check if the JS thread is busy?

Comment: Did you ever find a way to do this?

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can use `InteractionManager.runAfterInteractions` to wait until all rendering/animation is completed before running your computations. See the documentation [here](http://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/interactionmanager.html).

Comment: But this is still for user interactions. Know of any other way? 
Use case is, I need to wait for a pretty complex app to finish making API calls and rendering to do something.